# How to modify the behaviour of shortcut keybinding in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently in RStudio keybinding `CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + B` perform the following job
`devtools::install()`.

How can I change it to have this behaviour:

```
devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

If not, is it possible to create the entirely new keybinding for it?

Comment: Perhaps this might help?  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178?version=1.1.383&mode=desktop

Comment: @markdly No it doesn't because it only allows you to modify the keybinding of **RStudio predefined** function. I want to make a newly defined function.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute anything by using an add-in.  See https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/ for details.  In summary, you create a small R package containing a function like

```
installWithVignettes <- function() devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

then set up a special file in the package `inst/rstudio/addins.dcf` that names this as an add-in.  After that you can assign a shortcut to it.